# Netbeans how to load any type of file in my computer

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi I was wondering if there's a way that when I click a button on netbeans jframe , it will open any file in my computer example (loads an image/video/document)

Comment: For the future, Netbeans is just a development tool. You want to do it in **java**. That makes google search results a whole lot more relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Use Desktop.open(file) in button click handler. 
 
[SE7 Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File))

Answer (score 1):

There is a method to do this:

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    try {
        File myFile = new File("guide/guide.pdf");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                LocalizationService.localizeString("no_pdf"),
                LocalizationService.localizeString("no_pdf_tit"),
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

}

you can find example here http://www.journaldev.com/864/how-to-open-a-file-in-java

Comment: thanks a lot for your response!! Where should I put the file directory? I'm sort of a beginner so I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: I tried it ... I'm trying to add the code to an ''event mouse clicked'' in jframe ... but I keep getting an error :(

Comment: never mind!!! I got it to work!!! thanks alot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: One more thing I wanted to ask! so I managed to get my file to open which is a video (.mp4) ... is there a way how I can make it load in (fullscreen)?

Comment: @Chilam , First you maximize your mp4 reading software  window manually and close again and then run your program. It will open in maximized mode only.

Comment: thanks! lol sorry to ask again ... but I'm trying to make an ''X'' button image to be displayed on a label when its clicked I was wondering if there's a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Create a `File` object (or get one from a JFileChooser) correponding to what you want to open , then use [Desktop.open](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)) :

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
if(file.exists()) 
   desktop.open(file);
```

This method states :

> Launches the associated application to open the file

Also note the exceptions you may get  :

> **NullPointerException**
>    - if file is null
>
> **IllegalArgumentException** 
>   - if the specified file doesn't exist
>
> **UnsupportedOperationException** 
>   - if the current platform does not support the Desktop.Action.OPEN action
>
> **IOException** 
>   - if the specified file has no associated application or the associated application fails to be launched
>
> **SecurityException** 
>   - if a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkRead(java.lang.String) method denies read access
>   to the file, or it denies the
>   AWTPermission("showWindowWithoutWarningBanner") permission, or the
>   calling thread is not allowed to create a subprocess